# FFmpeg and reverb

Tags: c, audio, ffmpeg

How to FFmpeg can manage audio channels to create effects such as reverb?

Answer (score 2):

FFmpeg is not really intended to apply effects. You can add a reverb using **sox**, the audio swiss army knife. Its manual is well written!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to produce a decent reverb on a clip of someone singing where the output to video bypassed the reverb:

ffmpeg.exe -i input.mp4 -map 0 -c:v copy -af aecho=1.0:0.7:20:0.5 reverb.mp4

I found similar on another question but the suggestion there sounded bad.

aecho parameters:

1.0 - Overall volume.  Leave this at 1.0 or the whole audio track will be quiet.

0.7 - Volume of the echo effect as a percent.

20 - ms to delay echo.  If you want reverb, this value should be between 10 (warm) and 50 (echo chamber reverb).  Don't go beyond 50 or it will turn into a cave-like echo.

0.5 - Leave the decay at the default of 0.5